# ChartJS hide y-axis when dataset is hidden via legend

Tags: reactjs, charts, chart.js, react-chartjs

I am trying to hide the corresponding `y-axis` when the dataset is turned off via legend. I have 3 datasets on a single chart and all of them have their own `y-axis` assigned to it, here is an example of 1/3:

[image]

Now inside `legend config` I have a following code:

```
export const getChartLegendConfig = chart => {
    return {
        onClick: (click, legendItem, legend) => {
            //START handling legend click.
            const datasets = legend.legendItems.map((item, index) => {
                return item.text;
            });
            const index = datasets.indexOf(legendItem.text);

            if (legend.chart.isDatasetVisible(index) === true) {
                legend.chart.hide(index);
            } else {
                legend.chart.show(index);
            }
            //END handling legend click.

            //This is supposed to toggle y axis for a toggled dataset.
            // chart.scales[`y${index}`].display = false;
            chart.scales.y1.display = false;
            chart.scales.y2.display = false;
            console.log(chart);

            chart.update();
        }
    };
};
```

At the moment Im trying to hardcode 2 y-axis (`y1` and `y2`) to be hidden on the legend click, but nothing happens, what am I doing wrong? `console.log` before `chart.update()` shows that `display` values are `false`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are changing the scales objects but you should change the chart configuration, because you are going to invoke the update of the chart.

See doc: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html#updating-options

```
chart.options.scales.y1.display = false;
chart.options.scales.y2.display = false;
chart.update();
```